# How to select by attribute value using querySelectorAll if attribute value of placeholder contains slash and space

Tags: javascript, css

Let me explain example

```
<input placeholder='MM / YY'>
```

My query is `document.querySelectorAll('[placeholder=MM \/ YY]')`.

But it throws error `Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[placeholder=MM / YY]' is not a valid selector.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add quotes around the attribute value:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('[placeholder="MM \/ YY"]')
);
```

```html
<input placeholder='MM / YY'>
```

Comment: I didn't think this would work because if the element was `<input placeholder='MM'>`, the element could select by this querySelector `document.querySelectorAll('[placeholder=MM]')`

Comment: @RayKim the query selector method uses CSS selectors, and in css you need quotes for example `[type='text'] {width: 100%}`, so selecting the same elements would be `document.querySelectorAll("[type='text']")`

Comment: @SaymoinSam But if attribute value of selectors doesnt have space,  `document.querySelectorAll("[type=text]")` also work :)

Comment: Yes for attributes with no space you can do that but the preffered way is to use quotes